# OpenSSL file transfer

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, file-transfer

Is there API in OpenSSL for transfering files over safe SSL connection? Of course, it's not difficult to write some function myself using only SSL_read() and SSL_write() but if there is something already done, it'd be better.

Thanks

Comment: You really need an API?  Is a tool like [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) not enough?

Comment: *"Is there API in OpenSSL for transfering files over safe SSL connection?"* - well yes, but you have to write the program. But why not use `wget` or `cURL`?

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that implement some kind of protocol for that task. For example you can use sftp or scp. Give a look at functions like libssh2_sftp_open/libssh2_sftp_write/libssh2_sftp_read. They implement the client side of an sftp transfer. Another options is libssh2_scp_send that used scp.